# Error from chokidar after reinstalling np,

Tags: reactjs, npm-start, chokidar

I have a recurring issue with `npm start`.
First, it seems that every time after I removed everything in the `src` folder I will not be able to run `npm start` -- it will throw an error at start script.
I have been solving that problem with deleting node_modules and doing another npm install.
After that, `npm start` will run successfully, but it will give an `error from chokiar` saying that it's unable to watch my `index.css` and `index.js`.

Does anyone have a similar experience with this and have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by updating all packages to latest version.

To be safe, I deleted the the package-lock.json and the node_modules.

with

```
npx npm-check-updates -u
```

you will see the current and latest version.

run

```
npm install
```

to install the updates.

My `Error from chokidar` is gone. Hope it helps you too.